# Create page level comment with doxygen

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

I have an old php project with mainly functions rather than classes.  I am useing doxygen to generate documentation.  It is great.

However I cant seem to get it to generate a file level comment .  I have the following but it is ignored by doxygen or attributed to the first function

```
<?php 
/**
 This file has some functions
*/

 /**
   A function
 */
 function go() { 
  ...
```

`

Do I need to set a config option, am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at \file ?

Comment: 1.8.14 - I will take a look at \file and see if that works

Comment: worked, write it as an answer and I will accept it. @albert